# Give string values in vector an auto index

Tags: r, function, vector

i have two vectors:

```
names_of_p <- c("John", "Adam", "James", "Robert")
speeds <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Average", "Slow")
```

And i need the show to slowest person, i did it with if's and if else's, but i wonder if there is easier way to do it with like auto give "Slow" = 1 , "Average" = 2 and so on. In other words attach values to them.
At the end it should be vector like

```
names_speeds <- c(names_of_p, speed)
```

And then so i can compare persons and get who is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn `speeds` into an ordered factor, which would preserve the labeling while also creating an underlying numerical representation:

```
names_of_p <- c("John", "Adam", "James", "Robert")
speeds <- c("Slow", "Fast", "Average", "Slow")

speeds <- factor(speeds, levels = c('Slow', 'Average', 'Fast'), ordered = T)

names_of_p[order(speeds)]
[1] "John"   "Robert" "James"  "Adam" 

names_of_p[as.numeric(speeds) < 3]
[1] "John"   "James"  "Robert"
```

It might also be a good idea to store the data in a data frame rather in separate vectors:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  names_of_p = names_of_p,
  speeds = factor(speeds, levels = c('Slow', 'Average', 'Fast'), ordered = T)
)

df %>% 
  arrange(speeds)

  names_of_p speeds 
  <chr>      <ord>  
1 John       Slow   
2 Robert     Slow   
3 James      Average
4 Adam       Fast   

df %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(speeds) < 3)
    
  names_of_p speeds 
  <chr>      <ord>  
1 John       Slow   
2 James      Average
3 Robert     Slow
```

Comment: Yes, thank you thats exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

First assign `names` to the vector `speeds` then you get a named vector.
After that you can use `which`:

```
names(speeds) <- names
which(speeds=="Slow")
```

```
  John Robert 
     1      4
```

Comment: I see, but the problem is that, the slowest don't have to be slow, it could be also Average if there is no slow option. So i would like to automate it with "values" to those speeds so i can easliy compare them etc.

Comment: Oh and also i make a mistake, names should be normal vector not names function. i will edit it